# what is "services are not specified" mean in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

There is nothing wrong with my logic, but when I run it, it said services are not specified, I never meet this kind of problem, could anyone can help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYdBC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3xT1.png)

This is one of the information I got after I click on the hyperlinked blue text
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2fYy.png)

Comment: This appears to just be a simple setup issue in your model logic. Please provide more information, a) what type of model are you building? Pedestrian process flow, agent-based. I assume pedestrian. b) Please provide a screenshot of the blocks you are using. c) What do you get if you click on the hyperlinked blue text in the error console.

Comment: Yes, I used Pedestrian process flow. I will attach the pic in my question

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to replicate your error by simply dragging the objects from your screenshot to the canvas, but the error is slightly different

[image]

In mine screenshot it also says `Parameter 'services' is not specified!` ahere in yours it says `<unknown> : Service not specified`

However I see that you are using AnyLogic 7 and not 8, is it possible for you to upgrade?

The problem is that you need to specify  an actual animation area for your pedService blocks

[image]

In fact, all pedestrian library objects require to be connected to some animation object to work